# How to enable sticky sessions on a LoopbackJS app running on CloudFoundry/Bluemix

Tags: socket.io, ibm-cloud, loopbackjs, cloud-foundry

I have a LoopbackJS app deployed on IBM Bluemix and horizontally scaled across 3 instances. This app also uses Socket.io to implement a chat system.

I'd like to activate sticky sessions so that each request coming from the same client is routed to the same app instance.

I know that sticky sessions are supposed to be avoided according to the [12 factors](https://12factor.net/). But it seems to be the only solution in order to have socket.io working properly with multiple nodes.

As stated [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html), seems like I need to set a JSESSIONID session cookie in the loopback application.

I then did the following in the server.js of the LoopbackJS app:

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 's3Cur3',
  name: 'JSESSIONID',
  proxy: true,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

After making that change, when I issue a request to the Loopback app, I can see that two cookies are set in the response headers:

```
Set-Cookie:__VCAP_ID__=988ce9aa9b7f49cdb31d04f697d892b6024579565ea443589ed10e7a4c1c05f0; Path=/; HttpOnly, JSESSIONID=s%3Adb3KsqgZfkwEg39wrLKcsB3AWpazcOgd.TcA1vYbVB5DqemJXDS%2BLxUJ207WNC7UGmS5BpjZQ9Xc; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=s%3Adb3KsqgZfkwEg39wrLKcsB3AWpazcOgd.TcA1vYbVB5DqemJXDS%2BLxUJ207WNC7UGmS5BpjZQ9Xc; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

Anyway, when I issue the request again from the same browser, I can see in the logs on the Bluemix side that the request is served by a different app instance.

I'm really inexperienced on those subjects, so would really appreciate any advice that would help to properly configure sticky sessions.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/rajaraodv/redispubsub

Answer (score 0):

Per https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html#sessions

"On subsequent requests, the client must provide both the JSESSIONID and VCAP_ID cookies. The CF routing tier uses the VCAP_ID to forward client requests to the same application instance every time."

e.g. pick VCAP_ID and supply alongside with JSESSIONID

Comment: The problem seems to be that the VCAP_ID cookie is not stored by the browser when coming back in the response headers alongside with the JSESSIONID cookie. The JSESSIONID cookie gets stored but not the VCAP_ID. Therefore, only the JSESSIONID cookie is sent in the headers of the second request. Any idea why the VCAP_ID cookie is not saved?